# jQuery moving elements up and down the row

Tags: jquery, sorting

I would like to be able to move div elements up/down, in this case I cant use jQuery sortable, since the element, needs to be moved manually one at the time.

Here is my html:

```
<div>First <a class="up">UP</a> | <a class="down">DOWN</a></div>
<div>Second <a class="up">UP</a> | <a class="down">DOWN</a></div>
<div>Third <a class="up">UP</a> | <a class="down">DOWN</a></div>
<div>Fourth <a class="up">UP</a> | <a class="down">DOWN</a></div>
```

and here is js:

```
$(".up,.down").click(function(){
    var row = $(this).parent("div");
    if ($(this).is(".up")) {
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    } else {
        row.insertAfter(row.next());
    }
});
```

The above works partially, sorting down is fine, but up, every top row disappears into top of the page, prepended to body tag.

Comment: What browser and jquery are you using? Your code works as-is in my browser

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have figured out. All is needed to wrap all elements into a parent container

```
<section>
  <div>First <a class="up">UP</a> | <a class="down">DOWN</a></div>
  <div>Second <a class="up">UP</a> | <a class="down">DOWN</a></div>
  <div>Third <a class="up">UP</a> | <a class="down">DOWN</a></div>
  <div>Fourth <a class="up">UP</a> | <a class="down">DOWN</a></div>
</section>
```

and javascript:

```
$(".up").click(function(){
  var $current = $(this).closest('div')
  var $previous = $current.prev('div');
  if($previous.length !== 0){
    $current.insertBefore($previous);
  }
  return false;
});

$(".down").click(function(){
  var $current = $(this).closest('div')
  var $next = $current.next('div');
  if($next.length !== 0){
    $current.insertAfter($next);
  }
  return false;
});
```